# Why must I use getContentPane() instead of "this" when setting a BoxLayout for a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, boxlayout, contentpane

Why must I use **getContentPane()** instead of **this** keyword as a parameter argument for BoxLayout when setting a JFrame's layout to BoxLayout. To give a JPanel a BoxLayout, I must use **this** as a parameter.

I think this is because a JFrame has several layers or parts, which are the glass pane, layered pane, content pane, and menu bar. So the **this** keyword refers to the JFrame, but it does not refer to the content pane which we want to have a layout manager configured. That is why we invoke getContentPane() instead. I read that the content pane of a JFrame is actually a JPanel.

To summarize: BoxLayout's target parameter accepts JPanels but not JFrame, but JFrame's content pane is a JPanel.

```
class MyFrame1 extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame1() {    
        // This line does not work, why? 
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
    }
}

class MyFrame2 extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame2() {    
        // This line works
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel() {
        // JPanel uses "this" keyword
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }
}
```

Does a JPanel have multiple panes like a JFrame? What is the actual reason that I must use getContentPane()?

When the compiler says that BoxLayout can't be shared, does that mean that BoxLayout can not be shared between the multiple panes that compose a JFrame?

Comment: Does the compiler really say that?

Comment: Yes, it happens every time the first parameter (target) takes a bad argument.

Comment: I think no error occured because I had the correct code in MyFrame1 (that was an accident and I have changed it to include the incorrect code).

Comment: The compiler really says 'BoxLayout cannot be shared'?

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared"

Comment: Err, just as I suspected, that's an exception. Nothing to do with the compiler whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

A `JFrame` is a `Container`, but it's not the `Container` ["that needs to be laid out."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html#BoxLayout%28java.awt.Container,%20int%29) In contrast, the `Container`, returned by `getContentPane()` is one that can use an instance of `BoxLayout`. Alternatively consider the variation below that uses [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html), "A lightweight container that uses a `BoxLayout` object as its layout manager."

```
Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();
b.add(new JLabel("Test"));
f.setContentPane(b);
```

As tested:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23159430/230513 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();
        b.add(new JLabel("Test"));
        f.setContentPane(b);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```